# Distribution of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ if $X,Y$ are independent Beta random variables

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

Let $X \sim \text{Beta}(a,b)$ and $Y \sim \text{Beta}(b,a)$ be independent random variables.

What is the distribution of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$? Could it be Beta itself?

Comment: It is not a Beta distribution: experiment with $a_1=3,a_2=1$ and you will see something unlike any Beta distribution

Comment: It has a unique mode in $(0,1)$ and non-zero density at 0?

Comment: It can have as many as three modes.  Try, *e.g.,* $a=b=1/2.$  It can have zero density at $0$ and $1:$ try $a\ge 2$ and $b\ge 2.$  There's no "nice" closed formula for the density function.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what @Henry meant

Comment: I meant that experimenting showed a density shape which is clearly not a Beta distribution.  @whuber 's example is even more obviously not a Beta distribution

Comment: Special case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541322/cdf-of-x-xy-where-x-and-y-are-i-i-d-uniform

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This situation is described by T. Pham-Gia in 'Distributions of the ratios of independent beta variables and applications' in *Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods* Volume 29, 2000 - Issue 12 https://doi.org/10.1080/03610920008832632

For the variable $T = \frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}$ you get

$$f(t) = \begin{cases}
 t^{\alpha_1-1}(1-t)^{\alpha_1+1}\cdot B(\alpha_1+\alpha_2,\beta_2)\cdot {_2F_1}(\alpha_1+\alpha_2,1-\beta_1;\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\beta_2;\frac{t}{1-t})/A & \text{for $0 \leq t < 1/2$} \\
 t^{-(\alpha_2+1)}(1-t)^{\alpha_2-1}\cdot B(\alpha_1+\alpha_2,\beta_1)\cdot {_2F_1}(\alpha_1+\alpha_2,1-\beta_2;\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\beta_1;\frac{1-t}{t})/A & \text{for $1/2 \leq t \leq 1$ }
\end{cases}$$

with $A = B(\alpha_1,\beta_1)\cdot B(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$ and ${_2F_1}$ a hypergeometric function.